# variable extraction from equation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, equation

I'm trying to solve for T4 in the following equation in MATLAB, I have all other variables defined and I need to extract T4 from equation 1. Is there a quick way to do this rather than manually rearranging the equation for T4?

```
Wnet = 2046;
mdotair = 9741/147;
cp = 1005;
etaturb = 0.89;
etacomp = 0.9;
r = 12;
gamma = 1.4;
T2 = 280 ;
g = (gamma-1)/gamma;

Wnet = mdotair*cp*T2*(etaturb*(T4/T2)*(1-1/(r^g)-(1-1/r^g)-((r^g-1)/(etacomp)))); %equation 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is.

```
syms T4

Wnet = 2046;
mdotair = 9741/147;
cp = 1005;
etaturb = 0.89;
etacomp = 0.9;
r = 12;
gamma = 1.4;
T2 = 280 ;
g = (gamma-1)/gamma;

eqn = mdotair*cp*T2*(etaturb*(T4/T2)*(1-1/(r^g)-(1-1/r^g)-((r^g-1)/(etacomp))))-Wnet;

T4 = solve(eqn,T4);
```